# Retrieve sqlalchemy relationship objects in sorted order

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have the following relationship model in sqlalchemy:

`class User(Object):`

```
__tablename__ = 'username'

uuid = Column('uuid', BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
name = Column(String(20))
parent_name = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey(username.uuid')
children = relationship(
    "User",
    backref=backref("parent_name", remote_side=[uuid]),
    cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan",
    order_by="User.name"
)
```

When I have a user object from this table, say `user`, when I retrieve user.children, `order_by="User.name"` ensures that the list is ordered alphabetically. How can I customize/override the order_by functionality? For example, the name is stored in the db as "Firstname Lastname" and I want user.children to return a list sorted by last name.

Comment: You really want to store Firstname and Lastname (and Middlename) as separate columns. Then, if you want, you could create a computed column or property `name` to be `Firstname Lastname`.

Answer (score 1):

The table is already being used and there's a bunch of data which I dont want to migrate. I ended up fixing the problem by overloading the dot-operator:

`def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item == 'children':
            children = super(User, self).__getattribute__(item)
            children.sort(key=lambda x: x.name.split(' ')[1])
            return children
        else:
            return super(User, self).__getattribute__(item)`